# How to get argv from "struct linux_binprm"

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel

I want to use bprm_check_security lsm hook to check whether a process with specific arguments is allowed to run. In the documentation I saw that the argv should be available in @bprm (of type struct linux_binprm), but I didn't find any ways to extract the argv from the struct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -3):

bool tomoyo_dump_page(struct linux_binprm *bprm, unsigned long pos,
                      struct tomoyo_page_dump *dump)