# Get argv from bprm_check_security in linux kernel. Is the documentation wrong?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-security-module

According to [Linux Kernel's doc](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/lsm_hooks.h#L62):

> > `bprm_check_security`:
> > This hook mediates the point when a search for a binary handler will
> > begin.  It allows a check against the `bprm->cred->security` value
> > which was set in the preceding `creds_for_exec` call.  The `argv` list and
> > `envp` list are reliably available in `bprm`.  This hook may be called
> > multiple times during a single `execve`.
> > `bprm` contains the `linux_binprm` structure.

However, the value of `argv` and `envp` (e.g. `bprm->mm->arg_start`) are actually `NULL` at this point. This is due to the fact these values are setup in `setup_arg_pages` is called **after** the hook. Also, the `current` struct still points to the old process thus it cannot be used to get these data.

So my question is: Is the documentation incorrect or is there an alternate way to reliably get the arguments at this point?

---

Side note: I know that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198732/how-to-get-argv-from-struct-linux-binprm) already asks a quite similar question but I don't think it's a duplicate since this post asks a way to get argv from `bprm_check_security`, while I think that might not be possible thus I ask a confirmation that the issue comes from the doc. Additionally, no correct answer were given to this post.